# Dúvida Inserir Imagem com Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Amigos,

Seguindo os exemplos postados, fiz os ajustes:

```
        public ActionResult ThumbNail(int largura, int altura, string caminhofoto)
    {
        if (caminhofoto != "caminho" )
        {
            WebImage webImagem = new WebImage(@caminhofoto).Resize(largura, altura, false, false);
            return File(webImagem.GetBytes(), @caminhofoto);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Este ActionResult  a cima precisa receber o Jquery:

```
<script >

    function BuscarCaminho()
    {
        //Pega o elemento 'select'
        var select = document.getElementById("selecao");
        //Altera o valor do atributo 'src' da imagem para carregar a imagem selecionada
        if (select != "") {
            document.getElementById('caminho').src = select.value;
          //  alert(select.value);
        }
    }
```

Este é o Jquery Alterado, estou passando o caminho da foto:

```
        <div >
        <img id="foto" src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "ConsultaCliente", new {caminhofoto = "caminho", largura = 100, altura = 100 })" alt="thumbnail" />
    </div>


        <label>Foto:</label>
        <div id="selecao" onchange="BuscarCaminho()" >
            @Html.DropDownList("idFoto", String.Empty)
         </div>
```

Neste ponto, para cada foto selecionada eu quero enviar a imagem para ser visualizada na tela.
agradeço

Comment: Não entendi direito o que de fato você quer fazer.

Comment: o `onchange` está em uma div, e deveria estar no `select`. Talvez nesse caso seria melhor usar `html` mesmo ao invés da sintaxe `razor`.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na minha resposta. Se não suprir sua necessidade comente que eu vou modificando para tentar encaixar melhor no que você deseja fazer. por enquanto com a sua pergunta foi o que para fazer de acordo com o que eu entendi.

Answer (score 1):

Tente alterar o seu `javascript` para algo do tipo:

```
<script>
    function BuscarCaminho()
    {
        //Pega o elemento 'select'
        var select = document.getElementById("selecao");
        //Altera o valor do atributo 'src' da imagem para carregar a imagem selecionada
        document.getElementById('foto').src = select.value;
        //alert(select.value);
    }
</script>
```

E o seu `HTML` para algo assim:

```
<label>Foto:</label>
<div>
    <select id="selecao" onchange="BuscarCaminho()">
        <option value="caminho_da_foto1">nome_da_foto1</option>
        <option value="caminho_da_foto2">nome_da_foto2</option>
        <option value="caminho_da_foto3">nome_da_foto3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <img id="foto" src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "ConsultaCliente", new {caminhofoto = teste, largura = 100, altura = 100 })" alt="thumbnail" />
</div>
```

Comment: Amigo, agradeço, mais o caminho da foto vem de :
<div id="selecao" onchange="BuscarCaminho()">
    @Html.DropDownList("idFoto", String.Empty)
</div>

Comment: Eu preciso passar assim:

        <div >
          <img id="foto" src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "ConsultaCliente", new {caminhofoto = caminhoaqui, largura = 100, altura = 100 })" alt="thumbnail" />
        </div>

Comment: o problema é que a div não vai lançar o `onchange` ao mudar o `select`. Explique um pouco melhor do motivo pelo qual você "tem" que fazer assim.

Comment: Fiz a alteração da pergunta, ajustando o código de acordo com o que me enviou, veja se consegue ajudar.